# seamless input field css for document in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to do the same design as this nice invoice input field - http://css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice/

But as you can see in my Bootstrap 3 form, the input fields look horrible.

http://jsfiddle.net/gV6y8/16/

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control required" value="John Smith">
```

you could see all those with the input field has a horrible input box.

How can I make it similar as in the example editableinvoice (http://css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice/)? Basically the idea is the input fields are integrated seamlessly into the form, you don't see the borders, but only highlighted when you click on it and of course editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the input fields via CSS, something like this:

```
.form-control{ border:0;}
.form-control:hover{ background-color: #f00;}
```

Comment: thank you very much. i'ved updated it here http://jsfiddle.net/gV6y8/19/ but the input box height, padding and margins are off. i cant get it to nicely position it to be the same with without the input box.

Comment: if you look at this example, http://css-tricks.com/examples/EditableInvoice/, the input and non-input are all sized and positioned the same.

Comment: why not simply use the `height:` property? padding can't be negative, and thus your padding is ignored and css falls back to bootstrap's definitions.